# Printing an image in Blazor

Tags: c#, printing, blazor, mudblazor

I have a Blazor server application that stores user data. Each user has their own login details and a login code. Now I have a problem that I would like to output this code from the browser. I have the freeSpire.Barcode library. Now from the client side: when entering the application page, I would like to print the code and nothing happens. It means it saves the file where the application is on the server but does not open it. Do you have a proven way to print files from the client to the server?

```
 public void PrintCodeUser(int  id)
 {

     string imie = "";
     string nazwisko = "";
     string kod = "";
   


     using (SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(connectionToSql))
     {

         string sqll = "  SELECT Imie,Nazwisko FROM CompositeApps.dbo.Kamino WHERE id =" + id;
         try
         {
             var cmdd = new SqlCommand(sqll, con1);
             con1.Open();
             SqlDataReader rdrr = cmdd.ExecuteReader();

             while (rdrr.Read())
             {
                 if ((rdrr.IsDBNull(0))) { imie = "0"; } else { imie = rdrr[0].ToString(); }

                 if ((rdrr.IsDBNull(1))) { nazwisko = ""; } else { nazwisko = rdrr[1].ToString(); }
                 if ((rdrr.IsDBNull(2))) { kod = ""; } else { kod = rdrr[2].ToString(); }



             }

             con1.Close();

         }
         catch { /*MessageBox.Show("Error :)");*/ }

     }



     ////////////////// poczatek daty ////////////////

     string firstText =   imie + " " + nazwisko;

     string firstTextt = kod ;



     PointF firstLocation = new PointF(10f, 10f);
     PointF firstLocationn = new PointF(10f, 10f);
     PointF firstLocationnn = new PointF(10f, 10f);

     string imageFilePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile) + "\\tempkod11.png";
     Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(imageFilePath);//load the image file

     using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
     {
         //using (Font arialFont = new Font("Arial", 11))
         //{
         //    graphics.DrawString(firstText, arialFont, Brushes.Black, firstLocation);
         //}

         //using (Font arialFont = new Font("Arial", 8))
         //{
         //    graphics.DrawString(firstTextt, arialFont, Brushes.Black, firstLocation);
         //}
         using (Font arialFont = new Font("Arial", 14))
         {
             string napis = firstText;// + firstTextt;
         

             graphics.DrawString(napis, arialFont, Brushes.Black, firstLocationnn);

         }

     }

     bitmap.Save(@"C:\CompositeApps\tempkod22.png");//save the image file
     bitmap.Dispose();

     //DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Otworzyc plik do druku ? ? ?", "Zapytajnik", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
     //if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
     {

         Process process = new Process();
         process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
         process.StartInfo.FileName = "msedge.exe";
         process.StartInfo.Arguments = @"C:\CompositeApps\tempkod22.png"; //@"C:\temp\csct.json";
         process.Start();


         //    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile) + "\\tempkod22.png");

         //  System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile) + "\\tempkod22.png");

     }
     //else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
     {

         //  MessageBox.Show("Anulowano podglad");
     }

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you want to display a generated image, or download it to the user. If you save the image to a stream instead of a file, you can:

- Embed the image in the page like here in the Microsoft documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/images?view=aspnetcore-6.0#stream-image-data
- Trigger a download of the image like here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/file-downloads?view=aspnetcore-6.0#download-from-a-stream

You can use a MemoryStream and use the Save overload from the bitmap to output it to a stream:

```
using (MemoryStream myStream = new MemoryStream)
{
bitmap.Save(myStream, ImageFormat.Png);
}
```